# Connecting to SQL Server view with Windows authentication using Python?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, odbc, pyodbc, windows-authentication

I have access to the following view in a SQL Server database:

```
[Serverlocation\Server].[Server.DW.Application].[Application_AdHoc].[DepartmentDailySummary]
```

I am a beginner, I do not know too much about databases and views yet. I get an "InterfaceError 28000", which denies access to my user.

I tried to fit it in here:

```
conn_str = (
r'Driver=SQL Server;'
r'Server=Serverlocation\Server;'
r'Database=[Server.DW.Application].[Application_AdHoc].[DepartmentDailySummary];'
r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = cnxn.cursor(
```

Comment: You don't connect to a `VIEW`, you connect to the instance and database, and then *query* the `VIEW`.

Comment: `Database=[Server.DW.Application]` then you need to query the view as you would any other query `SELECT * FROM Application_AdHoc.DepartmentDailySummary`. Are you really still using SQL2008, are you aware it's long out of support?

Comment: Also, try to avoid names for objects that require delimit identifying (like your database's name). Using periods  (`.`) is especially confusing, as they are used as part separators.

Answer (score 0):

At first change your connection string to the following code:

```
conn_str = (
    r'Driver=SQL Server;'
    r'Server=Serverlocation\Server;'
    r'Database=Server.DW.Application.Application_AdHoc.DepartmentDailySummary;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
```

and use following changes:

```
import pyodbc

# Construct the connection string
conn_str = (
    r'Driver=SQL Server;'
    r'Server=Serverlocation\Server;'
    r'Database=Server.DW.Application.Application_AdHoc.DepartmentDailySummary;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)

# Establish a connection and create a cursor
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

# Now, you can use the cursor to interact with the database
```

chack the necessary permissions and the correct server and database names in your connection string to successfully connect to the SQL Server database. If you continue to encounter issues, please provide more information about your setup and any specific error messages for further assistance.